# How to load new set of data in existing Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

How can I REPLACE an existing hive table data with new set of data? NOTE: I don't want to drop the entire table and create new one. Rather i am looking for a method through which i can just replace the data from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OVERWRITE` while loading or inserting data.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/PATH/TO/DATA' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE MYTABLE
```

If the OVERWRITE keyword is used then the contents of the target table will be deleted and replaced by the files referred to by filepath; otherwise the files referred by filepath will be added to the table.